# Mock behavior of abstract class

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, spy

```
class A extends B
{
    method a(){
        b();
    }
}
abstract class B{
    void method b(){
        //dosomething
    }

}
```

I am testing method a of A class and need to mock the behaviour of method b of B class(call to b method should do nothing).
I am using Mockito framework for unit testing and tried spy with class A, but it worked only if another method being called lies in the same class but not in abstract class

Comment: Can you please add the code where you do the spy.

Comment: Try to understand the difference between spy and mock,spy is used when you want to inject constructors and mock is used just to create copy of object. So, spy makes actual call to dependent class.